# How can count the children of Drupal's main menu?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Is there a possibility to get the number of children of the main menu in Drupal (7)? 
I need to implement it in this part of the hook:

```
  if($item_id < NUMBER OF MAIN MENU CHILDS) {
  return '<li id="custom-menu-item-id-' . (++$item_id) . '"' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
  }
  else {
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
  }
```

This menu doesn't contain any subitems, but with children I mean every 'li' attribute.

Comment: Can you clarify children... suppose you have 3 paths: 'profile', 'account/join', and 'account/register' would join and register mean 2 children or would you consider all of those paths to be children of the root?

Comment: This menu doesn't contain any subitems, but I mean every <li> attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [menu_tree_page_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_page_data/7):

```
$num_top_level_children = count(menu_tree_page_data('main-menu'));
```